# Background size not working from common class is it needs any workaround

Tags: css

I am trying to set the background-size from shared class name. but not applying. if i add separately it works. is any issue with my code or it's expected from css standards? any one clarify me please?

Here is my css:

```
div.icon-item .icon{
    padding: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: contain; //common property not works.
}

div.icon-item .icon.blend {
    background: url(./images/blend-blue.png) no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.pour {
    background: url(./images/blend-blue.png) no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.air-dry {
    background: url(./images/blend-blue.png) no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.cut {
    background: url(./images/blend-blue.png) no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.package {
    background: url(./images/blend-blue.png) no-repeat;
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="anim-container">
        <div class="first">sss</div>
        <div class="anim-works" id="anim-visible">
            <div class="runner"></div>
            <div class="item-holder">
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon blend"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon pour"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon air-dry"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon cut"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon package"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="last">
            this is last anim
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML as well ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping - html part as well added.

Comment: `div.icon-item.icon`?

Comment: @wazz - yes. that's correct

Comment: change background by background-image .. your are overrideing the background-size with background (and use background-repeat:no-repeat for the repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stripped down example to fix your issue. The problem is with using the `background` property under a more specific selector. `background` sets the `background-size` property to it's default when you don't specify a value for it.

Changing your specific icons to use `background-image` and `background-repeat` directly fixes this.

```css
div.icon-holder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

div.icon {
    padding: 75px;
    background-size: contain;
}

div.icon.blue {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Lightblue.svg/900px-Lightblue.svg.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-holder">
  <div class="icon blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You add repeat property separtly `background-repeat:no-repeat;` also change background to `background-image`;

Then, add below style to `icon-item` class to align inline.

```
div.icon-item{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
div.icon-item{
    display: inline-block;
}
div.icon-item .icon{
    padding: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: contain;
}

div.icon-item .icon.blend {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.pour {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.air-dry {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.cut {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.icon-item .icon.package {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-container">
        <div class="first">sss</div>
        <div class="anim-works" id="anim-visible">
            <div class="runner"></div>
            <div class="item-holder">
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon blend"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon pour"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon air-dry"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon cut"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-item">
                    <span class="icon package"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="last">
            this is last anim
        </div>
    </div>
```

For More info : Visit
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp